# How to use mongo-connector with many collections and specific fields for every collection?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, connector

I want to use mongo-connector with ElasticSearch. I want to connect more than one collections and in every collection I want some specific fields. I know I can use comma separated names of collections with the "-n" and I know I can use "-i" with comma separated values to specify multiple fields. But how can I "tell" mongo-connector which fields belong to every collection. For example:

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager -n my_db.places,my_db.categories -i name,weight,rating
```

How will mongo-connector understand that "weight" belongs to "categories" and "rating" to "places"? And what happens if "name" exists in both(which is my case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you just add the fields you want from every collection in the fields list. The problem is that if you want one field from a collection and there is a field with the same name in another collection, it will also be transferred to the ElasticSearch.